# How do I create a 4VL "boolean" type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, logic, relational-database, relational-algebra

I am looking for a type that would have both TRUE and FALSE as per the normal boolean type, NULL (also as per the existing implementation, Codd's "A-Value" or Applicable unknown) and NA (Codd's "I-Value" or Inapplicable).

Example: imagine you have a set of medical tests for patients as attributes in a relvar, with patients as tuples. A test result that is not yet taken is of value NULL ("we don't know yet") but a female patient will never test for testicular cancer, and as such the value should be NA ("not applicable to this patient").

I am currently implementing it via an ENUM custom type (3VL as I assume NULLs will keep working without being declared):

```
CREATE TYPE triplebool AS ENUM ('true', 'false', 'na');
```

However, it requires casting existing boolean values to text then to triplebool:

```
SELECT has_taken_test::text::triplebool FROM test_record
```

Which is both inelegant, and means I have to use text values ('true', 'false', 'na') instead of the flexibility given by Postgres' true Boolean type (TRUE, t, 1; etc. + all the standard operations).

What I'd like is something that would look like (pseudocode):

```
CREATE TYPE triplebool AS (Boolean || 'na')
```

as well as the ability to define a truth table that includes the 'na' value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot extend (or create a new, extended type of) `boolean`, or any other scalar types that way. But you have 2 alternatives:

**1. Create an `enum` & enhance it.**

Like you tried, you could create an `enum` (ordering is important: it'll determine how it should be ordered by `order by`, indexes etc.).

```
create type triplebool as enum ('false', 'na', 'true');
```

You can make casts easier by [defining some custom ones](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html):

```
-- sample casts: from and to boolean

create function bool2triplebool(boolean)
  returns triplebool
  immutable
  strict
  language sql
as $func$
  select case $1
    when false then 'false'::triplebool
    when true  then 'true'::triplebool
  end
$func$;

create function triplebool2bool(triplebool)
  returns boolean
  immutable
  strict
  language sql
as $func$
  select case $1
    when 'false' then false
    when 'true'  then true
  end
$func$;

-- use implicit instead of assignment, if you want to
-- use this cast automatically in any expression,
-- not just in column assigments (in INSERT & UPDATE statement)
create cast (boolean as triplebool)
  with function bool2triplebool(boolean)
  as assignment;

-- this should be explicit (default)
create cast (triplebool as boolean)
  with function triplebool2bool(triplebool);
```

You can simulate some of the standard operations of `boolean`, if you want to. You can create custom [functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) & [operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createoperator.html) to achieve that:

```
-- sample operator: and

create function triplebool_and(triplebool, triplebool)
  returns triplebool
  immutable
  called on null input -- important, if you want to use null as the 4th "value"
  language sql
as $func$
  select res
  from (values (null::triplebool, null::triplebool, null::triplebool),
               (null,    'false', null   ),
               (null,    'na',    'na'   ),
               (null,    'true',  null   ),
               ('false', null,    null   ),
               ('false', 'false', 'false'),
               ('false', 'na',    'na'   ),
               ('false', 'true',  'false'),
               ('na',    null,    'na'   ),
               ('na',    'false', 'na'   ),
               ('na',    'na',    'na'   ),
               ('na',    'true',  'na'   ),
               ('true',  null,    null   ),
               ('true',  'false', 'false'),
               ('true',  'na',    'na'   ),
               ('true',  'true',  'true' )) t(lop, rop, res)
  where lop is not distinct from $1
    and rop is not distinct from $2
        -- "is [not] distinct from" can handle null values too
$func$;

create operator && (
  leftarg    = triplebool,
  rightarg   = triplebool,
  procedure  = triplebool_and,
  commutator = && -- for joins
);
```

But, as you can see, it is going to be a lot of work to implement almost all functionality of the `boolean` types. And it has a serious limitation: you cannot alter `enum` types' input and/or output functions (at least, in a reliable manner; you can start messing up with `pg_type`, but I'm not sure what will happen & your changes probably won't be exportable / dump-able, etc.). This means, you can only use the defined values (`false`, `na` & `true`) for input, no *alias* (like `f`, `1` with `boolean`) could be used (casting from and to `text` is an entirely different story, which can even be inconsistent with the IO functions of a type).

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b088f/1)

**2. [Create](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html) a truly [user-defined type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xtypes.html).**

With this option, you can create a true 4VL boolean type, but it comes with a cost, that it will be even more work than the `enum` option. And these types usually written in `C` (or in a language, which has appropriate bindings to PostgreSQL's source). You cannot write these low level IO functions in `sql`, nor in `plpgsql`.

**+1. Redesign your table schema (a little)**

While these solutions above *can* work, they make your data unportable. Also, if you need another column, which value is depends on the fact that those rows are applicable or not (like the test's date), are those new columns need an *n/a* state too? In my opinion, not. That datum should be in a different column:

```
create table med_test (
   -- ...
   is_applicable boolean not null,
   result        boolean,
   taken_at      timestamp with time zone
);
```

If you look at a row of this table above, you can clearly separate your cases:

- `is_applicable is false` means it is not applicable,
- `is_applicable is true and result is null` means it has not taken yet

You can optionally add integrity checks, to avoid *not applicable, but taken* state(s):

```
alter table med_test
  add check (is_applicable is true or result is null);

alter table med_test
  add check (is_applicable is true or taken_at is null);
```